# Where can I find an iPhone simulator for Xcode 3.1.4

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, development-environment, xcode3.2

My kids want to learn to write apps on their MacBook which currently runs OS version 10.5.8.

I have downloaded Xcode 3.1.4 but it doesn't seem to have the iPhone Simulator.

Does anyone know where I can find this?

(And are their better tags I should use for this question?)

Thanks.

(UPDATE: I down loaded the " xcode 3.2.6 & ios sdk 4.3" dmg file from Apple in the hopes of accessing just the "iPhone simulator" but repeated attempts to open the .dmg file on my OS10.5.8 Macbook result in a complete, "blackscreen" crash.)

Answer (score 0):

I am really very sorry because this is not straight to your question. But if I were you, I'd like to encourage them to start with Android. To me, an open-platform is more preferred. Beside that, Java is a strong/ dynamic language when comparing to C/C++.

- [Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/index.html)
- [Eclipse IDE](http://eclipse.org/)
- [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
- [ADT plugin for Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)
- [API guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/index.html)
- [Training videos](http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html)

Hope they will like  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the simulator was not included? One thing to remember is it won't be shown with xcode in your applications folder.

To use the simulator you have to launch it from xcode by pressing the play button in the top left corner of the interface. If you have already used xcode with an iPhone/iPod/iPad make sure you select simulator from the drop down next the play and stop buttons(press and hold to change what is selected).

If you want to make sure you can access the simulator without xcode, launch the simulator as described above and then right click(or ctrl click) the icon for the simulator and select keep in dock from the options menu.

Hopefully the above helps you with your problem. If xcode truly did not come with the simulator your best option is to uninstall xcode(after backing up any projects) and trying a fresh install. Also try checking Apples dev center (https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) for information about xcode and the simulator.

Comment: Unfortunately, when you are in xCode 3.1 there seems to be no "play" button. When you go to "File/New Project" it only allows the choices of Mac OSX Templates. There is no reference to the iPhone in any of the menus.